# Swift 2 migration error: no longer can pass in nil in the designated initialiser of SKSpriteNode

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, swift2, xcode7

Trying to migrate my project to Swift 2.

I get loads of compiler errors, most of which are easy to fix since they are merely syntax changes.

However, I don't know the best way to handle this error:

When calling the designated initialiser from my subclass of `SKSpriteNode` I get the error message: "Type 'UIColor' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'" for passing `nil` for the `color`:

```
import SpriteKit

class MyClass: SKSpriteNode {

  init() {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "MyTexture.png")
    super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: texture.size())
  }
}
```

I can work around this by passing in `UIColor.clearColor()` but I feel this isn't the proper way to handle this.

Any suggestions much appreciated, and also, what changed here (a link to an explanation would suffice, of course)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in Swift 1.2 the initializer you are calling on super used to accept an implicitly-unwrapped optional for the color, hence you were able to pass `nil`

in Swift 2, that same initializer no longer accepts an optional, you must pass a `UIColor` if you use it (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKSpriteNode/initWithTexture:color:size:))

your solution of passing `UIColor.clearColor()` seems reasonable to me!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, [according to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKSpriteNode/spriteNodeWithTexture:size:) (although not explicity stated, which is confusing), that if you're initializing with color, you'll need to pass an actual value other than `nil`.

I'm drawing that conclusion from the fact that you can initialize using just texture and size:

```
convenience init(texture: SKTexture?, size: CGSize)
```

Using this will not default color, which should give you the results you're looking for without necessitating a `UIColor` declarative of `UIColor.clearColor()`. However if you just initialize using texture, the color will be defaulted to white `(1.0,1.0,1.0)` and the size will inherit from the texture:

```
convenience init(texture texture: SKTexture?)
//The size property of the sprite is set to the dimensions of the texture. The color property is set to white (1.0,1.0,1.0).
```

Given this, I would assume (again, you're right, it's really confusing) that you'll need to pass some value, whether it's `RGB` or `UIColor`.

Comment: it's interesting to note that there are convenience initializers available that do not require you to pass a color, however you must call a designated initializer on `super`

Comment: Oh, I see, so are the convenience initializers for creating your own subclass of SKSpriteNode? I guess I'm confused on when they would be used.

Comment: out of convenience  :)  if you were happy with some default values being set for you, or if you specifically needed some additional behavior the initializer provides... in all cases, when you call a convenience initializer it will eventually call a designated initializer on that class, which then must call a designated initializer on its superclass - see "Class Inheritance and Initialization" here -> https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html (as well as "Designated and Convenience Initializers in Action")

Comment: I realized I could have been more explicit with my first comment: "when you write a designated initializer for a subclass, its implementation must call a designated initializer on it superclass", and "when you write a convenience initializer for a subclass, it must call either another convenience initializer or a designated initializer for your subclass - if you end up with a chain of convenience initializers being called, that chain must ultimately end with one of them calling a designated initializer for your class (which then, of course, calls a designated initializer on its superclass...)"